# Hi Team need help below error SQL not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, dql, dml

i was trying to update few columns in table through PLSQL block & columns has single inverted comma

```sql
update table_test set cname='Ameraca's Best' where siteid='4000012'
```

Getting error like SQL not ended correctly.
How to replace single inverted comma with double comma using ACSII hey or replace function

Comment: In SQL, you escape a quote by another quote:

SELECT 'America''s Best' from dual

Comment: This above update i was using inside the for loop of pkg and i couldn't use manually as
below and cname is coming from another source 
In SQL, you escape a quote by another quote: SELECT 'America''s Best' from dual – 
Pugzly
 2 hours ago

Comment: It's an example. The point is you need to escape the single quote. Do it as you see fit. If I'm missing your point reask your question with a simple test CASE, which shows your issue